# Shelve raises out of overflow pages

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, shelve

I have a lot of data that I read from a XML file, but only a part of it will be saved in the database later.

The XML is structured like that:

```
<element id="1" other_attrib="">
<element id="2" other_attrib="">
...
<other_element>
  <elem id="1">
  <elem id="100">
</other_element>
<other_element>
  <elem id...>
</other_element>
```

all of the `element` tags precede the `other_elements` tags, (this XML is third-party, I can't restructure it)

I have to read all of the `elements` first because they contain additional attributes, but only save those that are referenced by `other_element`s.

So I opened a `shelve` with `writeback=False`, use `lxml.iterparse()` to parse the XML and save elements on the go, but after many elements get added (I don't know the exact number, but it goes into hundreds of thousands) I receive the following error:

```
HASH: Out of overflow pages.  Increase page size
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  ...
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 133, in __setitem__
    self.dict[key] = f.getvalue()
```

Basically what I do is for every element `iterparse` returns:

```
if elem.tag == 'element':
  shlv[elem['id']] = {'attrib1': elem['other_attrib'], 'attrib2': elem['attrib2']}
elif elem.tag == 'other_element':
  # Here I iterate through this tags children and find references in shlv object
  for ref in elem:
    save_in_database(shlv[ref.attrib['id']])
```

What can I change so that `shelve` handles more data ? Or should I use something else to store that data ?

Comment: How do you store your IDs in the shelve? Can you give us some code?

Comment: @Squall I've updated the question

Comment: Since shelve acts like a dictionary, I think it's suffering from multiple hash collisions: Different IDs (which are of type `str`, if you just use `e.attrib['id']`) share the same `hash()` value. You could try iterating over the XML twice: first, you read and save the IDs of the `other_element`s in a `set()` (which results in lower memory usage, because you don't store entire elements). After that, you just get the `element`s you're interested in. You could also try using a plain `dict()` instead of shelve and maybe convert the IDs to `int` (which can't be used as keys for shelve). Good luck!

Comment: *this XML is third-party, I can't restructure it*...Sure you can with XSLT and python's lxml can run XSLT. Show your ideal restructuring. We can even source doc split into two XMLs!

Comment: @Parfait I don't know the size of OP's XML file, but lxml only supports XSLT 1.0, where you have to read the whole XML document into memory. You'd need an XSLT (3.0) processor that supports streaming transformations if your file doesn't fit into RAM.